# Set input:radio by jQuery then check checked by clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox, radio-button

**HTML :**

```
<label><input type="radio" name="type">Stackoverflow</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="type">Google</label>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$("input:radio").eq(0).attr('checked',true); // Set 1st input checked by jQuery

$("input:radio:not(:checked)").on("click", function(){
      console.log("yes!");
});
```

**Demo :** http://jsbin.com/onayec/1/edit

Look like HTML attr `checked="checked"` doesn't remove when click another `input:radio`

I just want to check if not click `input:radio` who `checked`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event instead of click would fire the event when the radio button click is not already checked.

```
$("input:radio").on("change", function(){
      console.log("yes!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
$('input:radio').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // do something
        alert('Ckecked');
    }
});
```

Comment: Try again, see the input tags are not closed well. close them `</input>` and it will work

Comment: What ? Have we to close `<input>` tags ? (talking about HTML)

Comment: Your demo : Got alert all time i clicked

Comment: Yes, we do need to close the input tags. Just try it once in jsbin

Comment: But your example http://jsfiddle.net/n2dxg/ with closed `<input>`tag doesn't work , Got alert alltime (click another & self clicking)

Answer (score 1):

Events are bound to elements not to their properties, ie, when you select an element, the handler is bound to that element, the handler is not updated when properties are changed, if you want to bind a click handler to input elements that are not `checked` you should use event delegation.

However, it's not a good example for radio/checkbox input elements, what you are after is a simple`change` event handler. The point was showing how events are bound to elements.